# OSX translate 32 to 64 bit GetVolParmsInfoBuffer

Tags: macos, 32bit-64bit

I have inherited legacy code circa OSX 10.5/10.7 which needs to be upgraded to OSX 10.9. I am finding that recommended code is now deprecated, but I don't know what to replace it with. For example, I have the following:

```
01  HParamBlockRec  pb;
02   
03  /* check parameters */
04  require_action((NULL != volParmsInfo) && (NULL != actualInfoSize),
05      BadParameter, result = paramErr);
06   
07  pb.ioParam.ioNamePtr = NULL;
08  pb.ioParam.ioVRefNum = volRefNum;
09  pb.ioParam.ioBuffer = (Ptr)volParmsInfo;
10  pb.ioParam.ioReqCount = (SInt32)bufferSize;
11  result = PBHGetVolParmsSync(&pb);
```

which a web search tells me can be replaced with

```
1   result = FSGetVolumeParms(volRefNum, volParmsInfo, sizeof(volParmsInfo));
```

However, this web page says that too is deprecated:[Framework
CoreServices/CoreServices.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html)

So a bunch more web searching finds the following [web page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/) which says: "The File Manager **was** a core service in OS X that managed the organization, reading, and writing of data located on physical data storage devices such as disk drives." It seems like the replacement methods require knowledge of what is being requested, where the previous methods went after information which the caller did not need to specify.

What is a way to figure out what the information is? The structure GetVolParmsInfoBuffer seems to be available, but how do I find example code on how to fill the structure when I don't know what to ask for?  Or do I play it safe and ask for every possible key?  That does not seem like good coding practice, but maybe it is the only solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You showed us the code leading up to the `PBHGetVolParmsSync` call, but if you look at the code after that, you may be able to figure out what the legacy code is trying to determine about the volume.

Comment: ` *actualInfoSize = (UInt32)pb.ioParam.ioActCount; 
 return ( result );
` And that's it.  So it is returning the full structure GetVolParmsInfoBuffer.  As well as how big it is (I think).

Comment: Why do you say it's returning the full structure?  The `result` of `PBHGetVolParmsSync` is of type `OSErr`, a numeric error code.

Comment: Because the call does fill the structure - that's a no error condition.  If it can't fill the structure it will give you an error return.  After reading a bunch more, I've come to the conclusion I'm attacking the problem from the wrong direction.  What I need to do is go up the chain of code and find the places where individual bits **are** checked, and use the framework there.  It is a change in philosophy, which seems pretty major.  I have to attack the problem with a completely different mind set - so the answer to the question I asked is "wrong question to ask!" Thanks!